# Weird 'theme update' error

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am developing a theme (which I am calling AsylumInfo) that gets built into a directory call `/build` and I have symlink from there to the wordpress setup on my computer.

When I use wp-admin I get the notification below. When I go to the theme chooser page and click 'update theme' button I see the following,.

[image: error]

When I click on the `View version 1.13` link I get taken to https://wordpress.org/themes/build/. In other words Wordpress appears to be looking at the directory name, not the theme name, before trying to find a non-existent update online. By private theme has no link at all to this published theme and **I want Wordpress to stop thinking that I need to upgrade**.

How can I get rid of this?  I imagine one option is renaming `/build` to `/asyluminfo`, which I can do but can't be necessary. Another is set the version of my theme to something > 1.13, but that's also arbitrary.

I can't believe this hasn't happened to someone else before?

Comment: This is just how the WordPress theme directory and automatic updates works, and it's happened before. It just looks for the folder name on WordPress.org. That's really all there is to it. The only workaround is to choose a different name or fudge the version number.

Answer (score 0):

For the details link you need to set `Details URI:` in the header of your theme's `style.css`...

Your `Theme Name:` also set there *should* create the slug the WordPress uses to query the wordpress.org theme repository for updates via the Update API. (I know for certain having tested it that slugs for plugins are created from the plugin name, I think it will be the same for themes but I haven't tested it specifically.)